# How to use css to convert a list in a text box to a bulleted list with a certain bullet jif

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following css script is my attempt to convert the content of a text box which is entered as a list; one item per line, into a bulleted list instead with a certain bullet.jif when it is displayed on the browser:

```
.correctanswerfeedback ul li {

display: table; 
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;       
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style:none;
background-image:url(\block_electronics-it.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0px 3px;
line-height:40px;
padding-left:50px;
font-size: 24px;
color: #307D7E;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: top;
width:auto;
float:none;
top: 10px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666;
}
```

This is an example of one item in a list created by js:

```
mattext texttype="text/html">this is the item I want to display bulleted</mattext>
```

Can I get some help with this issue please?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-image ? have you tried ?

Comment: From that link above, is there a way to refer/point to all list items  by address or position (or something else) eg "list-item0-n" in <li>list-item 1</li>, not item by item especially list items in the text box are dynamically changing?

Comment: ul li:nth-child(x) , might do :), if you had some live example, it would help you :)

Comment: Off topic, but `text-align:top` is wrong. You probably mean `vertical-align`. And what do you need `display:table` for?

Comment: I think I should've thought about it much deeper before asking my question. Mr Lister is right, this is off topic at this stage. So I believe this question should be closed. Many thanks for your comments.

Comment: I didn't say the question was off topic, I meant my remark was, because it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: My apologies, as sometimes lots of thinking may take one away from the core topic. Well, here is an item as an example that is created by js. how can I display it bulleted as indicated earlier:`<mattext texttype="text/html">this is the item I want to display bulleted</mattext>` .

Comment: @JosefMiller EHm, are you changing the question now? The original quesiton was about HTML; but this is not HTML.

Comment: The mere mentioning this highlighted the problem that perplexed me. I was all the time thinking html, and it is actually js output. I have edited my question in order to be more accurate in expressing my issue. Learning is a long process. Thanks Mr Lister.